# Easiest way to synchronize two databases

Tags: sql, magento

I have a database that stores the company's product stock (MSSQL running on a Windows server) and I'm creating a magento e-commerce (MYSQL running on a linux server). I’d like to know what would be the best way to update the inventory of the e-commerce (MYSQL) based on the company's stock. It will not be necessary to update the company’s stock after a sale through the e-commerce. I have full access to both databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The architecture in-vogue right now is to send stock updates into a queue (Service Broker, RabbitMQ), and have a process that handles the message by updating both databases. I.e., your application doesn't make database changes directly, it just sends messages into the queue.

That can be a big jump, though, so if that's too much effort up front you can just put a trigger on the SQL database and have the trigger also update the MySQL database, assuming you can set it up as a Linked Server in SQL.